Why would you negate a boolean `!(a == b)` instead of using not equals `!=` in Rust?
I was reading the Rust standard library and noticed an interesting pattern. A lot of conditions would be set up like this:
macro_rules! assert_eq {
    ($left:expr, $right:expr $(,)?) => {
        match (&$left, &$right) {
            (left_val, right_val) => {
                // Why are they doing it this way instead of using not equals?
                if !(*left_val == *right_val) {
                }
            }
        }
    };
}

At first I thought there was a seperate not equals trait but if you implement Eq/PartialEq you get Neq for free. I've seen this type of condition all over the codebase. Why do they do it this way?
I just saw this and was confused to what it means.

Likely an example of being pedantically pessimistic. Because == and != can technically be implemented in a nonsensical way, doing !(_ == _) will ensure that the == call is the one that is checked rather than the != call. Though I then find it amusing that assert_ne doesn't use !=.

Most likely it's a remainder of the fact that assert_eq! checked both directions of == and was written as !((*left_val == *right_val) && (*right_val == *left_val)) previously
